# When does it become overkill?

Tags: c#, .net

```
Moved: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/21128/when-does-it-become-overkill
```

Hi,

First off, I apologize cause I don't know how to make a community thread; so someone help me out please.

As a developer, across many platforms, technologies and even on an infrastructure level; I always find myself asking, when am I doing TOO much?!?

It's been a never ending learning process, since I started. One (1) thing I learned is that requirements are barely valid for an extended period of time, and as such a little foresight may go a long way.

But where is the balance, and how do you know when you're losing time, not gaining it?!

Comment: This is quite a vague question; what kind of answer are you expecting?

Comment: This question perhaps a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I will repost there then, whilst deleting here(?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit of a meta-answer, but I've always found that it's a fairly good rule of thumb that if I find that I'm asking myself "am I doing too much", then there's a fairly good chance I am.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I should post this elsewhere, I will. Another question, given your reputation: Should I have a certain minimum standard (1-2-3 guide) for all applications? I have found myself creating a Common library which i plugin everywhere!

Answer (score 1):

When you find yourself looking for patterns to use when you don't have specific problems to solve. Especially architectural patterns.

Answer (score 0):

These two articles might provide some insight on when you're doing to much:

- http://allankelly.blogspot.com/2010/10/reuse-myth-can-you-afford-reusable-code.html
- http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/papers/minimalism/TheImperialClothingCrisis.html